# Расположить блоки шириной 50% в строку

Tags: html, css

Почему когда задаю блокам .block ширину 50% , то они располагаются в колонку. А когда 49% то как мне нужно - в строку (казалось бы логично, что они должны занимать каждый по 50 % от ширины родителя)

```css
.wrap {
  background: #444;
  padding: 15px;
}

.block {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="block">Далеко-далеко, за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Они что приставка свое жаренные однажды? Ее своих курсивных единственное повстречался, проектах обеспечивает что океана, сих текст оксмокс он великий!</div>
  <div class="block">Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных, живут рыбные тексты. Дорогу переписали, однажды путь переписывается которой до? Бросил, если. Приставка, текста бросил если составитель алфавит своего однажды проектах имени до!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Задайте `.wrap{font-size:0;}`, а `.block{font-size:16px;}` или сколько вам нужно. Происходит это из-за межбуквенного интервала.

Comment: отлично. а если нужно задать блокам Margin-right? то они тоже выпадают из строки (даже если у последнднего блока обнулить margin-right)

Comment: @DaemonHK, поправочка, межсловного, а не межбуквенного.

Comment: задавайте padding'ом отступ в сочетании с `box-sizing: border-box`

Comment: @MedvedevDev да, спасибо)